# Jboss org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK issue

Tags: jboss, jgroups, mod-cluster

[org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (requester=, local_addr=) message ::port not found in retransmission table of :port:
 (size=xxxx, missing=x, highest stability=xxxxx)]

Comment: HI Anyone can provide the solution that why Iwe are getting above error and it's filling the log files

Comment: Could anyone provide the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

`NAKACK` (or its newer cousin, `NAKACK2`) provide reliable transmission of messages to the cluster. To do this, every messages gets a sequence number (seqno) and receivers deliver the message to the application in seqno order.

Every cluster member has a table of all other members and their messages (conceptually a list). When member P sends messages P21, P22 and P23, a receiver R first looks up the message list for R, then adds P21-P23 to the list.

However, in your case, the list for R was not found. This means that R was not a cluster member (anymore).

For example, if we have cluster {P,Q,R,T}, and member R leaves or is excluded because it was suspected (e.g. we didn't receive a heartbeat for a period of time), then messages P21-23 will be dropped by any receiver.

This is because JGroups only allows cluster members to send and receive messages.

How can a member get excluded?

This is likely done by on of the failure detection protocols (e.g. `FD_ALL` or `FD`).

Another possibility is that your thread pools were clogged and failure detection heartbeat messages were dropped, leading to false suspicions.

Also, long GC pauses can cause this.

Fixes:

- Increase the timeouts in `FD_ALL` or `FD`. The timeout should be longer than the longest GC cycle. Note that it will now take longer to detect hung members.
- Size your thread pools, e.g. make sure that the max number of threads are big and the queue is disabled.

Note that false suspicions *can* happen, but `MERGE3` should rememdy a split cluster later on.